# Extracting one property out of a JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsdata

I'm horrible at JSON. I don't understand a single thing. My JSON response looks like this:

```
 {
    ID = 1;
    EDate = "<null>";
    SelectedDay = "/Date(-62135596800000)/";
    End = "14.09.2013 15:00:00";
    Start = "14.09.2013 07:00:00";
    SDate = "<null>";
},
    {
    ID = 1;
    EDate = "<null>";
    SelectedDay = "/Date(-62135596800000)/";
    End = "14.09.2013 16:00:00";
    Start = "14.09.2013 07:00:00";
    SDate = "<null>";
},
```

In both NSData and NSDictionary. How can I loop trough, for example, the "End" property of each object, and add them to an array?

Edit:

I log from this code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result.data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response: %@",dict);
```

and the complete log is: 
[image]

Comment: What is the complete structure of your json ? are all these dictionaries stored in an array ?

Comment: @NishantTyagi This is the result when I log the response in both NSData and NSDictionary. Just like this. Bunch of these objects

Comment: Yes, most likely the outer layer is an array (whose "()" brackets you eliminated when you copy/pasted).  Copy the ENTIRE NSLog result (or at least the first part, that tells us how deep we are in what kind of object).

Comment: And go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then it will make a little more sense.

Comment: You see the "(" at the top?  That means it's an array.  This is confirmed by the fact that the array elements (which individually are NSDictionaries) are separated by commas, with no key values ahead of them (as you would see in a dictionary).

Comment: In JSON an array is bracketed by `[]` and an "object" is bracketed by `{}`.  In an Objective-C NSLog dump, an NSArray is bracketed by `()` (different from JSON) while an NSDictionary is bracketed by `{}` (same as in JSON).

Comment: So, even tho it's an dictionary when I made it, I can use standard array techniques to loop trough it? @HotLicks

Comment: It's not a dictionary if it dumps with `()` surrounding it, it's an array. The fact that you may have erroneously stored the pointer in one typed `NSDictionary*` has nothing to do with it, other than to make it a lot harder to invoke methods on the array. The object type is determined by the object, not the pointer, and the object coming from a JSON conversion is determined by the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JSON seems to be an array of dictionaries. Try with:

```
NSMutableArray *endValuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in JSONArray) {

     [endValuesArray addObject:[dictionary valueForKey:@"End"]];

}
```

Where JSONArray is the array obtained after NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just need an array of the values for a single key in each dictionary then you can use KVC:

```
NSArray *endValues = [resultsArray valueForKey:@"End"];
```

-- This is assuming that you do have an array of dictionaries and that your pasted log just doesn't show the full story.

If you need multiple keys / values out of the dictionaries then you're best to iterate over the contents and pick each item. There are various methods of iteration that you can look at using plain loops or blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
NSMutableArray *endDatesArray = [NSMutableArray new]; // Here this array will store all end dates
for (int i =0; i < [YOUR_JSONARRAY count]; i++) // Here YOUR_JSONARRAY is the response array you are getting 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict= [YOUR_JSONARRAY objectAtIndex:i];
    [endDatesArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"End"]];

}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: yours and rauru's answer helped me, yours could be improved with a for-in instead. thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

- Make an NSArray of the JSON Object.
- Use a FOR loop up to the count of the array to create an NSDictionary for each array object
- Use 'objectForKey:@"End"' to extract the End object. (within the for loop)

Comment: Why would you "make" an array when there's already one there??

Comment: But doesnt he have to assign the JSON data to an array to start with? He may already have done it, but I thought I'd include that for completeness.

Comment: He needs to assign the JSON data (which is presumably an array outermost) to an NSArray-typed pointer, but the JSON conversion "makes" the array.